# echo json_encode just shows data in browser and jquery cant get it (PHP MVC)

Tags: php, jquery

i built my own PHP MVC website . i want the admin can see the data's without refresh using jQuery and getJSON function

**index method in admins controller**

```
public function index(){
    session_start();
    if($this->isLogin()){
        echo json_encode($this->adminModel->getAdsWithNoPermission());

    }else{
        die("404 NOT FOUND");
    }

}
```

**Home method in admins controller**

```
public function home(){
    session_start();
    if($this->isLogin()){
        $this->view('admin/index');
    }else{
        redirect('pages/notfound');
    }
}
```

**Jquery script in admin/index view**

```
function adsOutput(){
    $.getJSON('<?php echo URL_ROOT;?>admins/index',function(data){
        var adminid = '<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_id'];?>';
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            $('#adsOutput').append('<tr>');
            $('#adsOutput').append('<th score="row">' + i);
            $('#adsOutput').append('<td>' + data[i].title + '</td>');
            $('#adsOutput').append('<td>' + data[i].subject + '</td>');
            $('#adsOutput').append('<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>');
            $("#adsOutput").append('<td><input type="submit" class="publish btn btn-success" value="publish" adid=' + data[i].id +  ' adminid=' +adminid +' ><input type="submit" class="delete btn btn-danger" value="delete" adid=' + data[i].id +  ' adminid=' +adminid +' ></td>' );

            console.log(data);

        })
    })
}
```

as you can see i wrote 2 methods home and index . the index just echo the data comes from model in json way . and the home return the homepage views . in the jquery function i'm getting json file from index page and shows data in the html. 
**codes works correctly** but i want to know how can i have just one index method like this

```
public function index(){
session_start();
if($this->isLogin()){
    echo json_encode($this->adminModel->getAdsWithNoPermission());
    $this->view('admins/index');
}else{
    die("404 NOT FOUND");
}

}
```

because when i wrote the index like this and remove the home method the output is this :  https://pasteboard.co/Hw62NKh.jpg

and if there is no way that i can handle all things in index method, and home method needs to be exist , how can i hide index methods (avoid admin to get there by URL) just to use it for jquery .

Comment: As a FYI, you are meant to have a single file which manages all the `session_start()` so you don't have to keep repeating it.

Comment: One way is to send a specific variable with ajax calls informing your script you only want json return. Then instead of echo'ing both json and the full page, you do one or the other based on that ajax called variable. Otherwise, you just need two entirely different methods as you have it, where all ajax calls go to one url, and all normal browsing goes to the other url. "which is better" is an opinionated question though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine two request like this. The index function should only return one thing, the page. Perhaps you could add an "arguments" parameter to your view method like

```
$this->view('admins/index',$this->adminModel->getAdsWithNoPermission());
```

And in your view, echo out the data into a JS object or HTML.

Note, you should set content type when you output JSON data. e.g.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: You don't *need to* set Content-Type for json return. Not with jquery.